# retrieve data from mongodb and link it with google charts

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, google-visualization

I'd like to retrieve data from database (mongodb) and with those data i'd like to draw à pie chart using google charts.
in a first case i have a collection called user and each user has a boolean attribute called (paid), i'd like to count how many paid users and free users and basing on those results i will draw a pie chart with the percentage of each kind of users

this my try i tried with for a long time but i'dont arrive to show the chart,

thanks :)

```
<?php
$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->pato->user;

$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor = $collection->find(array("paid"=>true));
$x=$cursor->count();
$cursor = $collection->find(array("paid"=>false));
$y=$cursor->count();
$myurl[]="['Option','Value']";
$myurl[]=[['Free users', $y],['Paid users', $x]];

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  </head>


     <script type="text/javascript">
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 function drawChart()
 {
    var data=google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    <?echo(implode(",",$myurl));?>
    ]);
    // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'User statistics',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('userStatsDiv'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
        chart.draw(data, options);
 }</script> 

 <body>
 <div id="usageStatsDiv" style="width:700; height:500"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in PHP, and even fixing that, your data structure is not quite right for the Visualization API.  Try this:

```
$myurl = array(
    array('Option', 'Value'),
    array('Free users', $y),
    array('Paid users', $x)
);
```

and then in javascript:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($myurl, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
```

Using `json_encode` allows you to transition from PHP arrays to javascript arrays and objects without worrying about the syntax of array and object construction.